# Resteasy client intialization causes Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.servlet.ServletContext

Tags: wildfly, resteasy

I am using Mandrill and I have set up a interface to user with resteasy client on Wildfly 18

```
public interface MandrillServiceRest extends ServiceRest {

    @POST
    @Path("/messages/send-template.json")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    Response sendTemplate(@HeaderParam("User-Agent") String userAgent, final MandrillSendTemplateRequest mandrillSendTemplateRequest);

    @POST
    @Path("/messages/send.json")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    Response send(@HeaderParam("User-Agent") String userAgent, final MandrillSendRequest mandrillSendRequest);

    @POST
    @Path("/users/ping2.json")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    MandrillPong ping(@HeaderParam("User-Agent") String userAgent, final MandrillPing mandrillPing);

    @POST
    @Path("/templates/info.json")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    Response templatesInfo(@HeaderParam("User-Agent") String userAgent, final MandrillTemplateInfoRequest mandrillTemplateInfoRequest);


    @POST
    @Path("/templates/add.json")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    Response addTemplate(@HeaderParam("User-Agent") String userAgent, final MandrillTemplateAddOrUpdateRequest mandrillTemplateAddOrUpdateRequest);

    @POST
    @Path("/templates/update.json")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    Response updateTemplate(@HeaderParam("User-Agent") String userAgent, final MandrillTemplateAddOrUpdateRequest mandrillTemplateAddOrUpdateRequest);
}
```

Seems ok but when I am creating the client :

```
ResteasyProviderFactory factory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();           ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers.class, factory);
        ResteasyClientBuilder resteasyClientBuilder = new ResteasyClientBuilder().providerFactory(factory);
        resteasyClientBuilder.connectionPoolSize(20);
        resteasyClientBuilder.socketTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ResteasyClient resteasyClient = resteasyClientBuilder.build();
        WebTarget target = resteasyClient.target("https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0");
        ResteasyWebTarget resteasyWebTarget = (ResteasyWebTarget) target;
        MandrillServiceRest mandrillServiceRest = resteasyWebTarget.proxy(MandrillServiceRest.class);
```

and this error occurs :

`org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.servlet.ServletContext`

I am currently trying to check on a new blank project...

BTW, it used to work in wildfly 10

Comment: It's hard to provide as answer without you giving any details as to what error/issue you are seeing

Comment: Sure. I digged so far and it is another ServletContext not found exception. I will edit the question after waking up 

Comment: update done, -> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.servlet.ServletContext

Answer (score 1):

I removed the use of ResteasyProviderFactory and it went well. Don't really know why. I will check this later but if anyone knows, I am glad to read an explanation :)